# Print Nothing Using Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to prevent anything from printing when a certain condition is met. For example, let's say I've suppressed every section for when `var="abc";`. However, when I try to print this report, a blank page gets printed. I'm using a Seagull printer and tearoff labels, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure section properties of 'New Page Before' and 'New Page After' are turned off for the suppress scenarios.